# Import ReactJS component from another file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React. Want to develop an app using little components in separate files and import them to my App.js

I tried but not be able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**Here is my html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>App</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/babel" src="js/App.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**This is my App.js:** (From js/ directory)

```
import MyComp from 'components/MyComp';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <MyComp />
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.body
);
```

---

**And this is my MyComp.js** (From js/components/ directory)

```
class MyComp extends React.Component{

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Hello World!
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default MyComp;
```

If I try this way I see nothing. Whereas if I create `MyComp` class in App.js it works like a charm.

Any suggestion what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For the most part, what you have should work, but I'm not quite sure why it doesn't.  I would recommend adding "./" to the import location, but if that was incorrect, it would error out and not silently go away.

Allow me to post an even simpler version which I know does work:

./index.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Application from './components/Application'

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

./components/Application :

```
import React from 'react';

class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        My Application!
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Application;
```

*This should be everything needed to make it work.*

If you want to shorten the above even more, by removing the `export` line at the bottom, a less traditional approach would be defining the class like this...

```
export default class Application extends React.Component {...}
```

Comment: "./" is the problem, Thanks @HoldOffHunger

Answer (score 1):

Try with

> ./components/MyComp

if you are using visual studio code, you could explore your components from any .js file by start typing ./ like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should add:
import React from 'react';
to the class Application extends React.Component {...

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to import components from another directory, use "../"
Example: `import Navigation from "../MainPage/Navigation";`

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this from Nhum here -
[Unable to import JS files with a project using CDN links (react, reactDOM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73760185/unable-to-import-js-files-with-a-project-using-cdn-links-react-reactdom)

If you're using CDN links to get React you have to define the modules you want to import in the head of the html and use data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd" in all the script elements with react code.  Applied here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>App</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="js/components/MyComp.js" data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/babel" src="js/App.js" data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Then the React code should run successfully.