# Cannot import react js component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I trying to import a react component to jsx file but it throws this exception:
[image: import error react]

This is my main code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";

class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <Sidebar/>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />, 
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

and this is my Sidebar component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Sidebar extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <h1>Hello Sidebar</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

My folders structure:

[image: Folder Structure react]

Comment: please share folder structure

Comment: PLEase check you path for SideBar component

Comment: Likely a path issue here.

Comment: Sidebar.js and App.js must be the same directory

Comment: Probably `import Sidebar from "./Sidebar.jsx";` will solve your issue.You might not have configured extensions to be resolved in webpack

Comment: Please post your webpack config here!

Comment: please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/44744673/5798019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you haven't added rule for .jsx file in webpack.config.js.

Since you have both .js and .jsx files you need to tell webpack to load files with extension .js and .jsx. Add below config to webpack.config.js in rules section

```
    {
        //tell webpack to use jsx-loader for all *.jsx files
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
    }
```

And add extensions like

```
   resolve: {
    modules: [
        path.resolve("./src"),
        path.resolve("./node_modules")
    ],
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  }
```

Below is the working webpack.config.js file for your ref

```
module.exports = {
    target: "web",
    entry: [
        "whatwg-fetch",
        'webpack-dev-server/client',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        'babel-polyfill',
        "./src/index.js"
        ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + 'build',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "index.html"
    }),
    new CompressionPlugin({
        asset: "[path].gz[query]",
        algorithm: "gzip",
        test: /\.js$|\.jsx$|\.css$|\.html$/,
        threshold: 10240,
        minRatio: 0.8
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // enable HMR globally

    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                //tell webpack to use jsx-loader for all *.jsx files
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {}
                  }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|ttf)$/,
                loader: "file-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve("./src"),
            path.resolve("./node_modules")
        ],
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    devServer: {
        watchOptions: {
        // Needed for Windows Subsystem for Linux dev environment:
            poll: true
        },
        contentBase: './build'
    },
    devtool: "cheap-module-eval-source-map",
    node: {
        child_process : "empty",
        fs: "empty"
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I post  simpler version which I know does work:

./index.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Application from './components/Application'

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

./components/Application :

```
import React from 'react';

class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        My Application!
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Application;
```

*This should be everything needed to make it work.*

If you want to shorten the above even more, by removing the `export` line at the bottom, a less traditional approach would be defining the class like this...

```
export default class Application extends React.Component {...}
```

Comment: I try that but it throws me previous exception. module not found